# Multiprocessing and pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have several excel files which I try to process and after processing merge into the total database. Each excel file can be processed separately, so I decide to use multiprocessing to speed this process. Unfortunately, I got an error `multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: [6811 rows x 5 columns]]'. Reason: 'TypeError("cannot pickle 'dict_values' object")'`

Code is as following:

```
def process_with_deals(file):
    ###some code to process DataFrame
    int_tot = int_tot.drop(columns=['deals'])
    return int_tot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exper = os.listdir('E:\ALLDataCourts')[:2]
    with Pool(2) as p:
        result = p.map(process_with_deals, exper)
```

I am kinda new to multiprocessing, so I would appreciate all possible help.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the dataframe? Unfortunately process communication is non-trivial and can only be done transferring relatively simple values. When a process wants to """return""" [cough, cough...] data to its parent, it uses the pickle module to serialize the data to transfer (to """return""" cough, cough...). Some values can not be pickled. It looks like your `int_tot` DataFrame contains one of those. Have you assigned any of your columns to some `dct.values()` ? Also, maybe [this other question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/99847) might help?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like this. I have found that my dataframe contains dct.values(). Transforming to lists solve the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that my dataframe contains dct.values(). Transforming to list solved the question.